# Count multilinestring elements crossing a raster cell in R

Tags: raster, r, rasterization, count

I have a shapefile with several `MULTILINESTRING` geometries, representing the borders of some species' distributions, and I want to count the number the number of species occurring in each cell.

I used the `rasterize` function from the `terra` package:

```
count.sp <- terra::rasterize(sp.lines, rast.w, fun = "count")
```

As an example, the lines in the figure below represent the borders of the distribution of a given species "X":

[image: Example with a species whose distribution is subdivided into several elements]

In the example, species' distribution was subdivided into several disjoint parts crossing the same raster pixel. With the code above, I got as a result the number of parts in each pixel (8 and 5, respectively), whereas I would like to get all the parts belonging to the same species and crossing the same pixel be counted as a single occurrence (i.e., I would like to get 1 in both pixels in the example below).

I also tried the function "sum" (with no field, and I obtained 208 and 130, I don't understand what these values represent)

[You can find some example data here (1 shapefile with just 2 species and the raster)](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19bXgDCAijRB8dSZgcr3IdoPBqrZVyy3H?usp=sharing)

What I am missing?

Comment: What answer do you want given the above data? I don't understand how you get "circles" from lines. In your shapefile, each row is a MULTILINESTRING object. Does one row = one species, and because its MULTI can be made of lots of little disjoint parts. Do you want to add 1 for every grid cell than any part of a MULTI-part object occurs in?

Comment: I would take a look at `terra::extract` rather than trying to rasterize. With the cells=TRUE argument, unique cell ID's are also returned which, allows for an aggregated count.

Comment: @Spacedman, "circles" are the borders of species' distributions, obtained from of original polygons after converting them to multilinestring elements. I  am using multilines geometries instead of original polygons because I want to count species occurrences even if the distribution does not touch the center of the pixel.

Comment: @Spacedman, I would like all disjoint parts belonging to the same species within a same pixel be counted as a single occurrence. In other words, for the distribution of the species in the figure above, I would like to get 1 in both pixels, insted of the number of disjoint parts in each pixel (that are 8 on the left and 5 on the right).

Comment: @JeffreyEvans, thank you for the suggestion, I achieved it following your hint, even if it would be simpler if it was possible directly with 
```rasterize```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [@JeffreyEvans](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/8520/jeffrey-evans) suggestion, I achieved it using an "extract" approach:

First, I assigned an unique ID to each raster pixel:

```
values(rast.w) <- 1:ncell(rast.w)
```

Then, I used the `extract` function from the package `terra` to get the ID of the cells crossed by each species:

```
sp <- terra::extract(rast.w, sp.lines)
```

Then, I converted the resulting list into a dataframe with the ID of each cell (first column) and the number of species occurring in each of them (second column, aggregated counting)

```
count <- as.data.frame(table(unlist(sp)))
```

Finally, I created a new raster from the first one, replacing ID values with the counting result:

```
newraster <- rast.w
newraster <- subs(rast.w, count, by = "test")
```